# Can I prove the solution set is non-empty by using rouche-frobenius?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $W = \{x-y+2z=3x+y=0\}$, determine if it is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. I only want to prove that the set is non-empty. Can I say that the matrix of coefficients it forms after applying gaussian elimination is compatible, therefore it has at least a solution and the set is non-empty?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An homogeneous linear system has always a solution...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: (0,0,0) is a trivial member of W.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside the comments which point out that $(0,0,0)$ is a solution, I will also note that there are obviously non-trivial (that is, non-zero) solutions as well; we have $y=-3x$ from the second equation, and so from the first $x-(-3x)+2z=0$ implies $z=-2x$, so for any choice of $x$ you get a solution $(x,-3x,-2x)$. Since there are infinitely many choices for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, this gives us plenty of non-zero vectors in $W$.

Comment: But can I prove that a subset of a field is non-empty by using Rouché-Frobenius? In the process of proving that it is indeed a subspace, to later prove closure under addition and scalar multiplication. My teacher insists that I need to explicitly construct at least one solution or show that there exists a vector that satisfies both equations.

Comment: The method I mention gives explicit solutions, just choose a value for $x$. You do not need a theorem at all to do it.